# Change specific RGB color pixels to another color, in image file

Tags: python, image-processing, colors, imagemagick, python-imaging-library

I would like to change a single color with Python.

If a fast solution with PIL exists, I would prefer this solution.

At the moment, I use

```
convert -background black -opaque '#939393' MyImage.png MyImage.png
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If `numpy` is available on your machine, try doing something like:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('fig1.png')
data = np.array(im)

r1, g1, b1 = 0, 0, 0 # Original value
r2, g2, b2 = 255, 255, 255 # Value that we want to replace it with

red, green, blue = data[:,:,0], data[:,:,1], data[:,:,2]
mask = (red == r1) & (green == g1) & (blue == b1)
data[:,:,:3][mask] = [r2, g2, b2]

im = Image.fromarray(data)
im.save('fig1_modified.png')
```

It will use a bit (3x) more memory, but it should be considerably (~5x, but more for bigger images) faster.

Also note that the code above is slightly more complicated than it needs to be if you only have RGB (and not RGBA) images.  However, this example will leave the alpha band alone, whereas a simpler version wouldn't have.

Comment: What if the original color is unknown, but the desired color to change the image to, is known? How could/should this be modified?

Answer (score 5):

This is a modification of Joe Kington's answer above. The following is how to do this if your image contains an alpha channel as well.

```
import numpy as np
import Image

im = Image.open('fig1.png')
im = im.convert('RGBA')
data = np.array(im)

r1, g1, b1 = 0, 0, 0 # Original value
r2, g2, b2, a2 = 255, 255, 255, 255 # Value that we want to replace it with

red, green, blue, alpha = data[:,:,0], data[:,:,1], data[:,:,2], data[:,:,3]
mask = (red == r1) & (green == g1) & (blue == b1)
data[:,:,:4][mask] = [r2, g2, b2, a2]

im = Image.fromarray(data)
im.save('fig1_modified.png')
```

It took me a long time to figure out how to get it to work. I hope that it helps someone else.

Comment: So `mask` ends up being an array of boolean values? How can that then be used for indexing for the `data` variable?

Answer (score 4):

I've just came up with this solution:

```
import Image
im = Image.open("MyImage.png")
width, height = im.size
colortuples = im.getcolors()
mycolor1 = min(colortuples)[1]
mycolor2 = max(colortuples)[1]
pix = im.load()
for x in range(0, width):
    for y in range(0, height):
        if pix[x,y] == mycolor1:
            im.putpixel((x, y), mycolor2)
im.save('MyImage.png')
```

Although putpixel isn't fast, it seems to be fast enough for me.

Comment: Probably doesn't make a difference speed wise, but you can do `pix[x,y] = mycolor2` instead of using `im.putpixel()`.

Comment: I tried this, but I get an error because of the mode ('r') in which I opened the Image. I tried `Image.open("MyImage.png", "w")` , but it doesn't work. I have no idea how I could use `pix[x,y] = mycolor2`

Comment: `im.getcolors()` will return `None` if the number of colors exceeds 256. So for huge images, this solution will not work.

Comment: @PhaniRithvij You can change that maximum, see [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getcolors). Interesting though that it exists in the first place

Comment: @MartinThoma So `im.getcolors(width*height)` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses `glob` to edit all pngs in a folder, removing a color and swapping it out with another, but uses RGBA.

```
import glob
from PIL import Image

old_color = 255, 0, 255, 255
new_color = 0, 0, 0, 0

for path in glob.glob("*.png"):
    if "__out" in path:
        print "skipping on", path
        continue

    print "working on", path

    im = Image.open(path)
    im = im.convert("RGBA")
    width, height = im.size
    colortuples = im.getcolors()

    pix = im.load()
    for x in xrange(0, width):
        for y in xrange(0, height):
            if pix[x,y] == old_color:
                im.putpixel((x, y), new_color)

    im.save(path+"__out.png")
```

It's a modification of https://stackoverflow.com/a/6483549/541208