# Simple jes Function to switch a pictures color from red to green or blue?

Tags: python, jython, jes

The title says it all, im just looking for a simple way to change all of a photos red pixels to green or blue.

Comment: Already ansewred here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483489/change-the-color-of-all-pixels-with-another-color

Comment: @Srinath: The accepted answer is not likely to work in Jython (since it uses NumPy).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean swapping the red and blue value for each pixel, then this is how you can do it. If not, there should be enough here to get you pretty close.

def swapRedwithBlue(sourceImage):

```
width = getWidth(sourceImage)
height = getHeight(sourceImage)

for x in range(width):
  for y in range(height):

    sourcePixel = getPixel(sourceImage, x, y) 
    R = getRed(sourcePixel)
    G = getGreen(sourcePixel)
    B = getBlue(sourcePixel)
    color = makeColor(B, G, R)
    destinationPixel = getPixel(sourceImage, x, y)
    setColor(destinationPixel, color)

repaint(sourceImage)
```