# How can I optimize my code? (python-opencv-numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('/home/user/Vision Artificial/fig_2.png')
tam = np.size(img, 0), np.size(img, 1)
cadena = '[255   0   0]'

for i in range(tam[0]):
    for j in range(tam[1]):
        if(str(img[i, j]) != cadena):
            img[i, j] = [255, 255, 255]

cv2.imwrite('/home/user/Vision Artificial/out.png', img)
```

`cadena` contains the color that I want to save

For example:

`input:`

[fig_2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKAP2.png)

```
output:
```

[out.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnAZp.png)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483489/change-the-color-of-all-pixels-with-another-color

Comment: For the moment I can't do this works for my. I'll keep trying. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conversion of the integer array to a string is slow.
Instead, compare integer arrays directly, using numpy.array_equal.

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import time

    start_time = time.time()
    img = cv2.imread('/home/user/Vision Artificial/fig_2.png')
    tam = np.size(img, 0), np.size(img, 1)
    target_BGR = [255, 0, 0]

    for i in range(tam[0]):
        for j in range(tam[1]):
            if not np.array_equal(target_BGR, img[i, j]):
                img[i, j] = [255, 255, 255]

    cv2.imwrite('/home/user/Vision Artificial/out.png', img)

    print(time.time() - start_time)
```

Note: It's also possible to avoid the explicit loops and use `np.apply_along_axis` with `axis=2` but this does not provide performance benefits here.

Comment: This reduce the execution time from around 60 to 10 seconds. I did't know about np.array_equal(), I like it. Thanks