# change white background to a specifc color

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Hello I am trying to give a black and white photo a colored background, first I convert pixels to either white or black then I would like to replace the white with a specific color (148,105,39) then save it.

here is the image I am working on [image: logo1.jpg]

here is my function so far it doesn't change the color (also doesn't give error)

```
def binary_image(img):
    gray = img.convert('L')
    bw = gray.point(lambda x: 0 if x<128 else 255, '1')
    img = bw.convert('RGBA')
    pixdata = img.load()
    for y in range(img.size[1]):
        for x in range(img.size[0]):
            if pixdata[x, y] == (255, 255, 255, 255): #white color
                pixdata[x, y] = (148,105,39,255)
    return full_4
img=Image.open('logo.jpg')
bg_fps = binary_image(img)
bg_fps.show()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the color of all pixels with another color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483489/change-the-color-of-all-pixels-with-another-color)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really, really want to avoid `for` loops with PIL images, try to use Numpy and it will be easier to write and faster to run.

I would do it like this:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import image

# Load image and ensure greyscale
im = Image.open('U6IhW.jpg').convert('L')

# Make Numpy version for fast, efficient access
npim = np.array(im)

# Make solid black RGB output image, same width and height but 3 channels (RGB)
res = np.zeros((npim.shape[0],npim.shape[1],3), dtype=np.uint8)

# Anywhere the grey image is >127, make result image new colour
res[npim>127] = [148,105,39]

# Convert back to PIL Image and save to disk
Image.fromarray(res).save('result.png')
```

[image]

---

You could equally use PIL's `ImageOps.colorize()` like this:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

im = Image.open('U6IhW.jpg').convert('L')                                                                                                           

# Threshold to pure black and white
bw = im.point(lambda x: 0 if x<128 else 255)                                                                                                        

# Colorize
result = ImageOps.colorize(bw, (0,0,0), (148,105,39))
```

Comment: 1 question, if logo was written in another color (say golden) how can I keep original color as well

Comment: Where I create a solid black image with `res = np.zeros(...)` you could initialise it to solid gold with `res = np.zeros() + [212,175,55]`

Comment: can you elaborate more on that?

Comment: I used `[212,175,55]` as gold, but use any RGB values you like.