# Image processing: IndexError when trying to change color of a pixel

Tags: python

I have to change color of all the black pixels of an image with a given color, so I was following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6501902/9952624) and found out it was working well. Then I resized the input image (scaled down, in my case) and I got this error:

```
red, green, blue = data[:, :, 0], data[:, :, 1], data[:, :, 2]

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

The code is just as in the answer posted above. I don't know much of image processing so I can't guess why this happens.

### EDIT

The source images are the following: first one is working, the latter isn't.

[image] [image]

Comment: What is the information in data? Or at least provide data.shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It likely is caused by your image not being in RGB format, it's perhaps a paletted image in which case the colour values are just a single integer and data will only be a 2D array without the 3rd coordinate for red/green/blue. You can either work with the paletted colours, in which case you can compare a known color number with `data[:,:]` directly, or you can keep the RGB code shown in your original post and convert the image to RGB with

```
img_rgb = img.convert('RGB')
data = np.array(img_rgb)
red, green, blue = data[:, :, 0], data[:, :, 1], data[:, :, 2]
```

(I'm assuming here that the image and other variables are the same as the post you linked to)

Comment: Thanks! Ended up working, still I don't understand why just resizing the image caused this weird behaviour.