# Is there a shorter/simpler version of changing a multidimensional array?

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array `data` made from an RGBA image, and in this code I change the color of the image using the original color (from black to white) as the brightness for the new color: `r`, `g`, `b`, `a`

```py
data[:,:,0] = data[:,:,0]/255*r
data[:,:,1] = data[:,:,1]/255*g
data[:,:,2] = data[:,:,2]/255*b
data[:,:,3] = data[:,:,3]/255*a
```

The code works correctly.
But I think changing the `data` array could be written shorter and better

I tried to do something similar like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6501902/22701738), using `mask`, but unfortunately I still didn't understand how I could adapt this short code to my needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use broadcasting:

```
data = data / 255 * [r, g, b, a]
```

You could compare the results to what you have.